# Counting MODIS burned area pixels inside a grid in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, vector-grid

I am using MCD64A1.006 MODIS Burned Area Monthly Global 500m product in GEE and trying to count the number of pixels with a value inside of each grid cell in a vector grid I created.

```
// load MCD64A1 Version 6 Burned Area

    var dataset = ee.ImageCollection(imageCollection)
                      .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
                      .filterBounds(border);
    var burnedArea = dataset.select('BurnDate')

// add grid

Map.addLayer(grid, {color: 'white'}, '1degree grid', true);

// count pixels

var pixC = burnedArea.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: grid,
  scale: 500,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

print(pixC)
```

a link to the grid asset: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/stavo/Vectorgrid_1degree

I assumed that if I provide a multipolygon as a geometry for the reducer I will get a separate result for each grid cell. However, I receive a count of all existing pixels in all cells.

Is there a way to get a count for each cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and it was quite simple. I used `.reduceRegions` instead of `.reduceRegion`, and it did the trick.